Convergence rate of a nonlineaer function
Assuming that we have an estimator of $\theta$, we obtain $\hat \theta$.
If we have $$\| \hat \theta -\theta \|_2^2 = O_p(1/n)$$
can we get $$\| f( \hat \theta) - f(\theta) \|_2^2 = O_p(1/n)$$?
e.g.:
Does $\| \hat \theta -\theta \|_2^2 = O_p(1/n)$ implies $\| \hat \theta^2 - \theta^2 \|_2^2 = O_p(1/n)$ or $\| \hat \theta^3 - \theta^3 \|_2^2 = O_p(1/n)$ ?
Are there any recommended books/papers to learn that?
It seems to be related to the Delta method. However, from what I found, the Delta method usually describes the property of convergence but not the rate. I am wondering whether the rate are the same.
Many thanks!

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
